# Can programSubscribe capture accounts that are closing?

Tags: websocket, programsubscribe, pubsub

An example of parsed account data from programSubscribe:

```
{
  "info": {
    "isNative": false,
    "mint": "EePJGdJHNn8DunCcQsLFBtGpkg9pPoZDV6JiVCVSTkib",
    "owner": "Eevo32bdg1SWUWCnTTxY5wZvnnxWqWmPiDG4LLMfNP7x",
    "state": "initialized",
    "tokenAmount": {
      "amount": "0",
      "decimals": {
        "$numberLong": "6"
      },
      "uiAmount": 0,
      "uiAmountString": "0"
    }
  },
  "slot": "256774749",
  "type": "account"
}
```

Shows us that account data state is being updated. For simplicity sake, in the context for token accounts, how do we tell (from programSubscribe) if the account is about to be closed? (Assuming, "about to be closed" already happened on-chain, and the node was about to tell us about that via programSubscribe)

If programSubscribe is not the way, what is the way? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to detect that an account has been closed through `programSubscribe`, since it'll only notify based on the *new* state of the account.

You would need to also subscribe to the system program to detect when an account is closed, and also keep track of token accounts in your program. This isn't an amazing solution though, because you'll get tons of unnecessary notifications and need to store much more info about all token accounts seen.

There's a PR to do this in Geyser https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/pull/43 but not for normal websockets just yet.

Comment: Hey Jon! Mind elaborating a bit more about "subscribe to the system program" to make it clearer for other readers when they find this again? (i.e. using programSubscribe, etc) Thank you!!! Appreciate it.